# Where would I ask a question about the Kuril Islands Dispute?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Having gone through the various sites we have available--and bear with me if I missed one; there are over 150--I've become stumped as to where I could ask a question regarding the Kuril Islands Dispute. I'm particularly interested in finding out more about what would happen if either Russia or Japan took full ownership of one or more of the islands. Research has not brought up too much for me thus far, but I'm certain someone with the knowledge exists somewhere within this network of sites.

Regardless, I'm left wondering which site to propose my question?

Comment: Maybe [Politics.se]? I don't know enough about their scope to know for sure.

Comment: What-if questions, like [this one](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/13834/what-would-happen-to-egypt-if-the-nile-were-dammed) are not always well-received on Politics.

Comment: If the dispute has been going on a long time, and ownership has flipped repeatedly, then perhaps History could give you some insight into the issues at stake at what it was like under one rule or the other in the past?

Comment: @KateGregory That's actually a really good idea. This dispute is around 70 years old, which I would think is long enough, but there's history going very far back about the difference in ownership of the islands. Three nations (the third being the Ainu) have a valid claim to these islands. I might try History for this, if I don't find a reason why the question would be removed.

Answer (score 4):

That's pretty wide-open, and I'm not certain how you could narrow it down. We do have [Politics SE](//politics.stackexchange.com), but your question is open to a great deal of speculation and interpretation in the manner that you're looking to ask it.

But you *could* ask what all parties have at stake regarding the disputed territory, I'm sure you could get a pretty detailed answer to that, which could lead you to being able to better envision what would happen if (say) Japan fully asserted itself in the matter.

Just be very specific - you're more looking to discover why each party sees them as valuable enough to maintain such a lengthy dispute. From that, you could better extrapolate individual priorities, and then form a better speculative assessment of what would happen if any party escalated the dispute such as you describe.